# Sort a dict in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict

```
dictExample = {4:'Yellow',2:'White',3:'Blue',1:'Black'}
```

I need it get sorted based on Id as a dict

Desired output:

```
{1:'Black',2:'White',3:'Blue',4:'Yellow'}
```

which should be a dict

Can some one help me. I am new to python.

Comment: Dict are unorder by definition in python. Check OrderedDict from collections package.

Comment: @Cheche: As of Python 3.7, the language says they’re ordered.

Comment: There are answers on the dup which deal with all the major Python releases 2.7 onwards.

Comment: @jjp Wow!!.. gonna check that!... thanks

Comment: Still not able to figure this out :(